# How to check that method has been invoked in arquillian test

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, jms, jboss-arquillian

I'm testing jms with arquillian and wilfdly server. Here is a simple test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class PubSubMdbAsyncJmsTest {

    public static final String MESSAGE_1 = "Test message1";

    @Inject
    PubSubProducer pubSubProducer;

    final AtomicBoolean hasBeenInvoked = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Produces
    public Function<String, Void> messageConsumer() {
        return new Function<String, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void apply(final String message) {
                Assert.assertEquals(MESSAGE_1, message);
                hasBeenInvoked.set(true);
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClass(PubSubProducer.class)
                .addClass(MdbConsumer.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        System.out.println(jar.toString(true));
        return jar;
    }

    /*
     */
    @Test
    public void testSendMessageAndConsumeItSuccessfully() throws InterruptedException {
        pubSubProducer.sendMessage(MESSAGE_1);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.wait(5);
        Assert.assertTrue(hasBeenInvoked.get());
    }
}
```

Test is run under arquillian and wilfdly. The `Assert.assertTrue(hasBeenInvoked.get());` check fails. If you change the Function to (add throwing an exception):

```
   @Produces
    public Function<String, Void> messageConsumer() {
        return new Function<String, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void apply(final String message) {
                Assert.assertEquals(MESSAGE_1, message);
                if(true) throw new RuntimeException(message);
                hasBeenInvoked.set(true);
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

You'll see this RuntimeException with a correct message ("`Test message1`"). Which means that the `apply` method has been invoked. It's not clear, why the `hasBeenInvoked` is still false?

The produced Function is used in MDB bean and, I think the implementation of this bean is not needed. As I said, as soon as you throw  an exception, you can see that method is invoked. The question is, why the last assertion is failed in test?

As an alternative, maybe I could use mockito to check whether the `apply` method has been invoked or not, but how can I use it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use :

`TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);`

instead of

`TimeUnit.SECONDS.wait(5);`